# Add thousands separator in a number

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, string

In python

```
 re.sub(r"(?<=.)(?=(?:...)+$)", ",", stroke )
```

To split a number by triplets, e.g.:

```
 echo 123456789 | python -c 'import sys;import re; print re.sub(r"(?<=.)(?=(?:...)+$)", ",",  sys.stdin.read());'
 123,456,789
```

How to do the same with bash/awk?

Comment: FWIW, Python has had built-in support for formatting numbers with the comma separator since 2010 (versions 2.7 and 3.1), so you don't need to do the regex trick. Example: `print('{:,}'.format(123456789)) #=> 123,456,789`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ echo "123456789" | sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)/\1,\2,\3/g'
123,456,789
```

(Note that this only works for exactly 9 digits!)

or this with `sed`:

```
$ echo "123456789" | sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/,&/;ta'
123,456,789
```

With `printf`:

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=en_US printf "%'.f\n" 123456789
123,456,789
```

Comment: I'm also trying with awk but it's add comma at the last `echo 123456789 | awk '$0=gensub(/(...)/,"\\1,","g")'`

Comment: now I get but it's seems complex `echo 123456789 | awk '$0=gensub(/(...)/,"\\1,","g"){sub(",$",""); print}'`

Comment: That first `sed` only works if the number is exactly 9 digits. The `printf` doesn't work on zsh. Thus the second `sed` answer is probably the best.

Comment: @RahulPatil That only works properly if the number of digits is a multiple of 3. Try with "12345678" and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Johan - yeah, just confirming that that doesn't work for me either.

Comment: You can do `echo 123456789 | awk '{printf ("%'\''d\n", $0)}'` (which evidently doesn't always work on Linux!?, but works fine on AIX and Solaris)

Comment: @DepressedDaniel - it looks like you're hitting the byte limit that a float can handle.

Answer (score 73):

`bash`'s `printf` supports pretty much everything you can do in the `printf` C function

```
type printf           # => printf is a shell builtin
printf "%'d" 123456   # => 123,456
```

`printf` from coreutils will do the same

```
/usr/bin/printf "%'d" 1234567   # => 1,234,567
```

Comment: This is now supported in `zsh` too, updated post [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140320).

Comment: I'm on bash 4.1.2 and it doesn't support... :(

Comment: @msb It seems to depend on your system's `vsnprintf`.  On a GNU/Linux system, glibc appears to have supported it since at least 1995.

Comment: Note printf uses the thousands [separator for your current locale](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-number-formatting-in-with-thousand-separator/), which might be a comma, dot, or nothing at all. You can `export LC_NUMERIC="en_US"` if you want to force commas.

Comment: Get list of supported locale's with `locale -a`.  I had to use `en_US.utf8`

Comment: @eludom and beware `LC_ALL`, since `LC_ALL=C` overrides `LC_NUMERIC=en_US.utf8`.

Comment: Watch out for leading zeroes. They will cause `printf` to treat the number as an octal value (e.g. 01 = 1, 011=9, 0111=73) and return the equivalent decimal.

Put another way, this code: `num="0123456"; result=$(printf "%'d" "$num"); echo "$result"` will return a result of 42,798 and not the expected result of 123,456.

Comment: Also if you want to pipe the number to `printf` then you can use xargs: `echo 12346789 | xargs printf "%'d"`

Comment: doesn't seem to work with Alpine linux/busybox: `sh: %'d: invalid format`

Answer (score 20):

You can use numfmt:

```
$ numfmt --grouping 123456789
123,456,789
```

Or:

```
$ numfmt --g 123456789
123,456,789
```

Note that numfmt is not a POSIX utility, it is part of GNU coreutils.

Comment: A neat thing about long options is that they can be abbreviated (as long as the abbreviation is unique).  For example, ``ls --color`` can be written `ls --col` (but not `ls --co`, because there is also a `--context` option). It turns out that `--grouping` is `numfmt`’s only option that begins with **`g`**, so `--g` is a unique abbreviation.

Comment: Just don't use abbreviated forms in scripts, because some day, the one you used might stop working.

Comment: This does not work for me in coreutils 8.30.  (I wonder if `LC_ALL=C` overrides `LC_NUMERIC=en_US.utf8`?)

Comment: And that was the problem...

Answer (score 7):

```
cat <<'EOF' |
13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084096
EOF
perl -wpe '1 while s/(\d+)(\d\d\d)/$1,$2/;'
```

produces:

```
13,407,807,929,942,597,099,574,024,998,205,846,127,479,365,820,592,393,377,723,561,443,721,764,030,073,546,976,801,874,298,166,903,427,690,031,858,186,486,050,853,753,882,811,946,569,946,433,649,006,084,096
```

This is accomplished by splitting the string of digits into 2 groups, the right-hand group with 3 digits, the left-hand group with whatever remains, but at least one digit. Then everything is replaced by the 2 groups, separated by a comma. This continues until the substitution fails. The options "wpe" are for error listing, enclose the statement inside a loop with an automatic print, and take the next argument as the perl "program" (see command perldoc perlrun for details).

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Comment: Thanks to anonymous for the feedback. Even a downvote can be useful, but only if explained -- please comment on what you saw that was wrong. Thanks ... cheers

Comment: I think the downvote here is because you did not explain what the command does.  The OP asked for a `BASH`/`AWK` alternative so he may not have used `PERL` before.  In any case, best to explain what the command does - especially so for one-liners.

Comment: @AnthonyK -- thanks for probable explanation. I added comments to briefly explain how it works. I think alternative solutions are often useful, but your point about possibly not having used perl is noted ... cheers

Comment: I tried the sed and python suggestions on this page.  The perl script was the only one that worked for a whole file.  The file was filed with text and numbers.

Answer (score 5):

`awk` and `bash` have good built-in solutions, based on `printf`, as described in the other answers. But first, `sed`.

For `sed`, we need to do it "manually". The general rule is that if you have four consecutive digits, followed by a non-digit (or end-of-line) then a comma should be inserted between the first and second digit.

For example,

```
echo 12345678 | sed -re 's/([0-9])([0-9]{3})($|[^0-9])/\1,\2\3/'
```

will print

```
12345,678
```

We obviously need to then keep repeating the process, in order to keep adding enough commas.

```
sed -re ' :restart ; s/([0-9])([0-9]{3})($|[^0-9])/\1,\2\3/ ; t restart '
```

In `sed`, the `t` command specifies a label that will be jumped to if the last `s///` command was successful. I therefore define a label with `:restart`, in order that it jumps back.

Here is a bash demo (on [ideone](http://ideone.com/XIo0FC)) that works with any number of digits:

```
function thousands {
    sed -re ' :restart ; s/([0-9])([0-9]{3})($|[^0-9])/\1,\2\3/ ; t restart '
}                                                 
echo 12 | thousands
echo 1234 | thousands
echo 123456 | thousands
echo 1234567 | thousands
echo 123456789 | thousands
echo 1234567890 | thousands
```

Comment: This is like an addon for bash lover, i was strungled with the locale stuff, thankfully found this gem. very practical,  just need to paste this one line of code somewhere inside the shell, and use it whenever needed. Btw, it's hard to understand what the code does, the only thing i know is i can replace the ”,” with ”.”

Answer (score 3):

With some `awk` implementations:

```
echo "123456789" | awk '{ printf("%'"'"'d\n",$1); }'  

123,456,789
```

`"%'"'"'d\n"` is: `"%`(single quote)(double quote)(single quote)(double quote)(single quote)d\n`"`

That will use the configured thousand separator for your locale (typically `,` in English locales, space in French, `.` in Spanish/German...). Same as returned by `locale thousands_sep`

Comment: a maybe cleaner way is : `awk '{printf("%\047d\n",$1); }'`, and awk will translate the octal 047 into a single quot before interpreting the printf string, avoiding you this weird string of quote and doublequotes. You can force a specific locale (*if* it is installed...) : `LC_NUMERIC=en_US awk ....` (or fr_FR if you want spaces, and if it is installed)

Answer (score 2):

A common use case for me is to modify the output of a command pipeline so that decimal numbers are printed with thousand separators. Rather than writing a function or script, I prefer to use a technique that I can customise on the fly for *any* output from a Unix pipeline.

I have found `printf` (provided by Awk) to be the most flexible and the memorable way to to accomplish this.  The apostrophe/single quote character is specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) as a [modifier](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html) to format decimal numbers and has the advantage that it’s locale-aware so it’s not restricted to using comma characters.

When running Awk commands from a Unix shell, there can be difficulties entering a singe-quote character inside a string delimited by single-quotes (to avoid shell expansion of positional variables, e.g., `$1`). In this case, I find the most readable and reliable way to enter the single-quote character is to enter it as an *octal* escape sequence (beginning with `\0`).

Example:

```
printf "first 1000\nsecond 10000000\n" |
  awk '{printf "%9s: %11\047d\n", $1, $2}'
```

```
  first:       1,000
 second:  10,000,000
```

---

Simulated output of a pipeline showing which directories are using the most disk space:

```
printf "7654321 /home/export\n110384 /home/incoming\n" |
  awk '{printf "%22s: %9\047d\n", $2, $1}'
```

```
  /home/export: 7,654,321
/home/incoming:   110,384
```

---

Other solutions are listed in [How to escape a single quote inside awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9899001/1640661).

Note: as warned against in [Print a Single Quote](http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote), it’s recommended to avoid the use of hexadecimal escape sequences as they do not work reliably across different systems.

Comment: Of all the awk-based answers listed on here, this one is most certainly the most graceful (IMHO). One doesn't need to hack in a quote with other quotes like in other solutions.

Comment: Thanks @TSJNachos117 The hardest part is remembering that the octal encoding for the apostrophe character is `\047`.

Answer (score 2):

A `bash`/`awk` (as requested) solution that works regardless of the length of the number and uses `,` regardless of the locale's `thousands_sep` setting, and wherever the numbers are in the input and avoids adding the thousand separator after in `1.12345`:

```
echo not number 123456789012345678901234567890 1234.56789 |
  awk '{while (match($0, /(^|[^.0123456789])[0123456789]{4,}/))
        $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART+RLENGTH-4) "," substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH-3)
        print}'
```

Gives:

```
not number 123,456,789,012,345,678,901,234,567,890 1,234.56789
```

With `awk` implementations like `mawk` that don't support the interval regex operators, change the regexp to `/(^|[^.0123456789])[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]+/`

Comment: This is great for using with any shell output, thanks.

Comment: Wow, finally found a correct thousand separator with `awk` in shell, because I tried many other ways but they behave different somehow different with some different numbers. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 1232323 | awk '{printf(fmt,$1)}' fmt="%'6.3f\n"
12,32,323.000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at BIG numbers I was unable to make the above solutions work.  For example, lets get a really big number:

`$  echo 2^512 |bc -l|tr -d -c [0-9]
13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084096`

Note I need the `tr` to remove backslash newline output from bc.  This number is too big to treat as a float or fixed bit number in awk, and I don't even want to build a regexp large enough to account for all the digits in sed.  Rather, I can reverse it and put commas between groups of three digits, then unreverse it:

`echo 2^512 |bc -l|tr -d -c [0-9] |rev |sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1,/g' |rev
13,407,807,929,942,597,099,574,024,998,205,846,127,479,365,820,592,393,377,723,561,443,721,764,030,073,546,976,801,874,298,166,903,427,690,031,858,186,486,050,853,753,882,811,946,569,946,433,649,006,084,096`

Comment: Good answer. However, I've never encountered a problem using large numbers with Awk. I tried your example on a number of Red Hat and Debian-based distributions but in all cases, Awk had no problem with the large number. I thought some more about it and it occurred to me that all the systems I had experimented on were 64-bit (even a very old VM running unsupported RHEL 5). It wasn’t until I tested an old lap-top running a 32-bit OS that I was able to replicate your issue: `awk: run time error: improper conversion(number 1) in printf("%'d`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a="13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084096"

echo "$a" | rev | sed "s#[[:digit:]]\{3\}#&,#g" | rev

13,407,807,929,942,597,099,574,024,998,205,846,127,479,365,820,592,393,377,723,561,443,721,764,030,073,546,976,801,874,298,166,903,427,690,031,858,186,486,050,853,753,882,811,946,569,946,433,649,006,084,096
```

Comment: That adds a spurious leading comma if the number of digits in the number is a multiple of 3.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: You could take the output of that last rev command, and pipe it to `sed 's/^,//g'`.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to have the part **after** the [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) correctly separated/spaced, therefore I wrote this sed-script which uses some shell variables to adjust to regional and personal preferences. It also takes into account different [conventions for the number of digits grouped together](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/182775/66573):

```
#DECIMALSEP='\.' # usa                                                                                                               
DECIMALSEP=','   # europe
    
#THOUSSEP=','  # usa
#THOUSSEP='\.' # europe
#THOUSSEP='_'  # underscore
#THOUSSEP=' '  # space
THOUSSEP=' '   # thinspace
    
# group before decimal separator
#GROUPBEFDS=4   # china
GROUPBEFDS=3    # europe and usa
    
# group after decimal separator
#GROUPAFTDS=5   # used by many publications 
GROUPAFTDS=3
    
    
function digitgrouping {
# FIXME: This is a workaround: BEGINNING has to be marked (and after                                                                
# alteration removed) for the first number to be spaced correctly (1234
# should be 1 234, and that only works if something is in front of that
# number).
sed -e 's%^%BEGINNING&%' \
  -e '
  s%\([0-9'"$DECIMALSEP"']\+\)'"$THOUSSEP"'%\1__HIDETHOUSSEP__%g
  :restartA ; s%\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\{'"$GROUPBEFDS"'\}\)\(['"$DECIMALSEP$THOUSSEP"']\)%\1'"$THOUSSEP"'\2\3% ; t restartA
  :restartB ; s%\('"$DECIMALSEP"'\([0-9]\{'"$GROUPAFTDS"'\}\'"$THOUSSEP"'\)*\)\([0-9]\{'"$GROUPAFTDS"'\}\)\([0-9]\)%\1\3'"$THOUSSEP"'\4% ; t restartB
  :restartC ; s%\([^'"$DECIMALSEP"'][0-9]\+\)\([0-9]\{'"$GROUPBEFDS"'\}\)\($\|[^0-9]\)%\1'"$THOUSSEP"'\2\3% ; t restartC
  s%__HIDETHOUSSEP__%\'"$THOUSSEP"'%g' \
  -e 's%^BEGINNING%%'

}
```

Comment: This will fail in the UK. Why not just use the Locale? There are no separators after the decimal point.

Comment: @JeremyBoden: By Europe I mean European Union.

Comment: The thousand separator is different in Spain (`.`), France (space) and Ireland (`,`) which are all part of the EU.

Comment: See also `locale thousands_sep` and `locale -k LC_NUMERIC` (on GNU systems at least)

Comment: Note that it assumes GNU `sed`. POSIXly and with several `sed` implementations, you can't have other commands after branching ones (`:`, `t`, `b`...). `\+` is also a GNU extension.

Comment: Beware `[0-9\.]` also matches on backslash (and potentially many characters or collating elements beside 0123456789 that sort between 0 and 9)

Answer (score 0):

The following uses space as thousands separator, which is the practice at my place. Modifying it for using comma should be easy.

```
echo "1000066955"|sed -rn "s/([[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]{3})$/\1 \2/;T end;:loop s/([[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]{3})[[:space:]]/\1 \2 /;t loop;:end p;"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
= Number grouping formatting using Perl RegEx =

[
|*| Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/656655
|*| Last update: CE 2021-08-18 06:44 UTC ]


Number grouping formatting (e.g. turning "1000000" into "1,000,000"; approximation of `numfmt --grouping`) using Perl RegEx:
(Unix Shell)
[
    PERLIO=':raw:utf8' exec '/usr/bin/perl' -p \
    -e 'BEGIN { $^H |= 0x02800000; $^H{reflags_charset} = 4; $/ = undef(); }' \
    -e '

    sub f {
    $x1 = $1;
    $x2 = $2;
#
# [
    if ( length( $x1 ) > 3 ) {
    pos( $x1 ) = length( $x1 ) % 3;
    $x1 =~ s/\G.{3}/ ( pos( $x1 ) != 0 ? "," : "" ).${&}; /gse;
    };
# ]
#
# Would work but inefficient:
# [
#   $x1 =~ s/(?<=\d)(?=(\d+))/ ( length( $1 ) % 3 != 0 ? "" : "," ); /ge;
# ]
# ,
# [
#   $x1 =~ s/(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/,/g;
# ]
#
    "${x1}${x2}";
    };

    s/(?<![\w#&)*,.\/:;=-\@\[-\]`{-}])([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?(?![\w#\$&(*\-\/<=\@\[-\]`{-}]|\.[^\W0-9])/ f(); /geu;

    ' \
    "$@";
]
[ Explanation Needed ]


Test case:
(Console Log (Unix) )
[
> \
    { nf <<\EOF
0.000000
10.000000
100.000000
1000.000000
10000.000000
100000.000000
1000000.000000
10000000.000000
100000000.000000
1000000000.000000
10000000000.000000
100000000000.000000
1000000000000.000000
EOF
    } | nf; # Verified idempotence.

0.000000
10.000000
100.000000
1,000.000000
10,000.000000
100,000.000000
1,000,000.000000
10,000,000.000000
100,000,000.000000
1,000,000,000.000000
10,000,000,000.000000
100,000,000,000.000000
1,000,000,000,000.000000
]
[ Alternatively: Try the full text of this message. ]




See also:
|*| "perlrun" - how to execute the Perl interpreter # "-i''[extension]''": https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-i%5Bextension%5D
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please use the proper formatting tools for your post, as currently it is very difficult to separate explanations from actual code.

Comment: [@AdminBee](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/377345): https://pastebin.com/wDmNQJpD