# Thousands separator in printf in zsh

Tags: zsh, printf, numeric-data

I have been trying to define a thousands separator in `printf` for a while now and I have discovered that zsh has some problems with it.

In bash I can use something like:

```
$ printf "%'d\n" 1234567890
1,234,567,890
```

but in zsh it won't work :

```
$ printf "%'d\n" 1234567890
printf: %': invalid directive
```

I have just found out that coreutils `printf` will do it just fine:

```
$/usr/bin/printf "%'d\n" 1234567890
1,234,567,890
```

How can I use thousands separator in zsh?

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: as of [`zsh v. 5.1`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/63ffbab84d5071bea0fdb2c8b16368283ec75253), the `printf` builtin supports grouping of thousands via `'` just like `bash`/`coreutils` `printf` (see also the discussion [here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2015/msg00765.html)).

---

The thousands separator is a [GNU extension that zsh doesn't support](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00756.html), and it has its own `printf` builtin that you end up using instead. As mentioned in the linked post, you can get the locale-dependant thousands separator with:

```
zmodload zsh/langinfo
echo $langinfo[THOUSEP]
```

If you need to use zsh specifically and exclusively, you can use that with sed.

Probably easier will be to use the non-builtin [`printf` from GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/printf-invocation.html) instead, which will permit the thousands separator option if your system does:

```
$ command printf "%'d\n" 1234567890
1,234,567,890
```

`command printf` tells the shell **not** to use a builtin or alias, but to look up the command in `$PATH`.

Comment: I suggest `command printf` instead of `/bin/printf`, which is not portable.

Comment: @jofel What is `command printf`?

Comment: Good point! I've edited that in. @Patryk, it skips builtins and looks up the command as though the shell weren't shadowing it.

Comment: @Patryk `commmand` forces the shell to use external commands and not any built-in commands (like `printf`, `time`, ...). More or less the opposite is the command `builtin`.

Comment: Ok, cool. Where can find some docs on that?

Comment: @Patryk: have a look in `man zshbuiltins`.

Comment: For the `zsh` manual, `info` is a lot better than `man` (especially with the `i` command to search the index). `info --index-search=command zsh`. Note that in sh emulation, `zsh` works like other POSIX shells, so `command printf` would invoke the builtin.

Answer (score 5):

To complement [Michael's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140320/22565), you could do the thousand-sep formatting by hand with `zsh` operators with:

```
var=1234567

zmodload zsh/langinfo
setopt extendedglob
echo $var[1,(l=-($#var-1)/3*3)-1]${var[l,l?-1:l]//(#m)???/$langinfo[THOUSEP]$MATCH}
```