# Printf formatting a ZSH variable without forking?

Tags: zsh, printf

For my powerlevel10k custom prompt, I currently have this function to display the seconds since the epoch, comma separated. I display it under the current time so I always have a cue to remember roughly what the current epoch time is.

```
function prompt_epoch() {
  MYEPOCH=$(/bin/date +%s | sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/,&/;ta')
  p10k segment -f 66 -t ${MYEPOCH}
}
```

My prompt looks like this:
[image: prompt example screenshot]

I've been told I can do this without the forked processes using these commands:

```
$ zmodload -F zsh/datetime p:EPOCHSECONDS
$ printf "%'d" $EPOCHSECONDS
1,648,943,504
```

But I'm not sure how to do that without the forking. I know to add the `zmodload` line in my `~/.zshrc` before my powerlevel10k is sourced, but formatting `${EPOCHSECONDS}` isn't something I know how to do without a fork.

If I were doing it the way I know, this is what I'd do:

```
function prompt_epoch() {
  MYEPOCH=$(printf "%'d" ${EPOCHSECONDS})
  p10k segment -f 66 -t ${MYEPOCH}
}
```

But as far as I understand it, that's still forking a process every time the prompt is called, correct? Am I misunderstanding the advice given because I don't think I can see a way to get the latest epoch seconds without running some sort of process, which requires a fork, correct?

Comment: Related: [Thousands separator in printf in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140316)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `printf` utility in both `bash` and `zsh` has a `-v` option that allows you to "print into a variable":

```bsh
printf -v MYEPOCH "%'d" ${EPOCHSECONDS}
```

The actual result of the above command may well be dependent on the current locale.

Comment: I was looking in completely the wrong place, thank you very much for a great answer. I really appreciate your help, you're the best!

Comment: The function `printf` in zsh is [documented here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-printf).

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, you can also do:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
set -o histsubstpattern -o promptsubst -o extendedglob
RPS1='$EPOCHSECONDS:fs/%(#b)([^,])([^,](#c3)(|,*))/$match[1],$match[2]'
```

To get something like `1,648,989,768` in your right prompt without forking a process nor relying on the locale for the value of the thousands separator.

`${param:fs/left/right}` uses the `s`ubstitute [history modifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) like in csh, while the `f` one repeats it as long as it changes something, achieving something similar to your GNU `sed` approach.

With the `histsubstpattern` option enabled, `left` can be a pattern, so `$param:s/left/right` behaves like ksh93's `${param/pattern/replacement}` except we can combine it with that `f` modifier which makes it more useful here.

Like with ksh93's `${param/pattern/replacement}`, the pattern can be preceded by `%` to match only at the end of the subject. With `extendedglob`, we can enable back-references with `(#b)` or use `(#c3)` to match 3 of the preceding atom like ERE's `{3}`.

Note that beside `$EPOCHSECONDS` (for which you need to load the `zsh/datetime` module), the epoch time can also be obtained with the `%D{%s}` prompt expansion. To be able to apply a modifier on it, you'd have to have it be expanded as part of parameter expansion though. That can be done with the `%` parameter expansion flag:

```
set -o histsubstpattern -o promptsubst -o extendedglob
RPS1='${${(%):-"%D{%s}"}:fs/%(#b)([^,])([^,](#c3)(|,*))/$match[1],$match[2]}'
```